# importing csv file into mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

```
> docker exec -it craig bash  
> mysql -u root -p --local-infile 
> use craigslist;
> 
> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/hank/Desktop/craigs/data.csv' 
> INTO TABLE books_mags  
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I have a csv file on my desktop that I am looking to enter into a MySQL table. But i am having a rough time figuring out the file path errors.

> ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'C:/Users/hank/Desktop/craigs/data.csv' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

I keep getting this error.

I am using a windows 10 and a docker containter for mySQL.

How can i put my csv into MYSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Directory path `C:/Users/hank/Desktop/craigs/data.csv` is in your host system(Windows). File system of your docker will be entirely different unless you have mounted the volume. Two ways to access the file inside the container

**First approach**

You'll have to mount the volume when you start the container

```
docker run -d image_name -v "C:/Users/hank/Desktop/craigs/:/data"
```

This is not always recommended.

**Second Approach**

Copy the file from your host machine to the container using `docker cp`

```
See 'docker cp --help'.

Usage:  docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
    docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
```

It is similar to copying files to remote server using `scp` command.

Answer (score 1):

1- Get you CSVs into your computer

2- Load them into your container, to manually get them there you can use:

```
docker cp file container:/<container-directory>
```

3- Enter your container and execute

```
> sudo docker exec -it jose_signot_mysql bash
container> mysql -uUser -pPassword
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/in/container/to/file' into table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

or execute script from outside, using an inline password (security issue)

```
  sudo docker exec jose_signot_mysql bash mysql -u<User> -p<Password> <databaseName> -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/in/container/to/file' into table <tableName> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;"
```

If you have an issue with secure-file-priv being set, when running this, in your instance check: this https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/447#issuecomment-403393323

Answer (score 0):

In order to import csv there are two solutions:

Adminer a tool for managing content for the relational databases (MySql, Postgresql, etc.)

Here below configuration for adminer in docker-compose.yml.
Then you can go to adminer by entering URL like "ip_addd_server:4041" then enter credentials of database ( host, password, dialect ) and log in.

```
 adminer:
  container_name: adminer
  image: adminer
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 4042:8080
  networks:
  - main-network
  depends_on:
   - db
```

Another solution to simply attach to the container and through this command.

```
docker exec -it db bin/bash // attach to container
```

Then you can log in with the correct user and import data through CSV file.